# Passing a function as a prop in react, Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and I'm creating a editable Pokémon list based on [this guide](https://www.kirupa.com/react/simple_todo_app_react.htm).

When I try to pass a function to edit a list item (at this point I want to click the item and get the name), I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined` on the following line of the `addPokemon` function: `onClick={() => this.edit(pokemon.name)}`

Code:

PkmnForm

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PkmnList from "./PkmnList";

class PkmnForm extends Component {

  static types = [
    'Bug',
    'Dragon',
    'Ice',
    'Fighting',
    'Fire',
    'Flying',
    'Grass',
    'Ghost',
    'Ground',
    'Electric',
    'Normal',
    'Poison',
    'Psychic',
    'Rock',
    'Water'
    ]

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      type: '',
      pokemons: [],
      caught: false,
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    var pokemon = {
      name: this.state.name,
      type: this.state.type,
      caught: this.state.caught
    };

    this.setState({
      name: '',
      type: '',
      caught: false,
      pokemons: this.state.pokemons.concat(pokemon)
    });
    event.preventDefault()

  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleTypeChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      type: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  editPokemon(name) {
    console.log(name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>Register a Pokémon</h1>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

              <input 
                required
                placeholder=" Name"
                name="name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.name} 
              />
              <br />
              <select 
                name="type"
                required
                value={this.state.type}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              >
                <option value='' disabled>Type</option>
                {PkmnForm.types.map(
                  optionValue => (
                    <option
                      key={optionValue}
                      value={optionValue}
                    >
                      {optionValue}
                    </option>
                  )
                )}
              </select>
              <br />
              <label>
                Caught
                <input
                  name="caught"
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={this.state.caught}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </label>
              <br />
              <button type="submit">Add Pokemon</button> 
            </form>
          </div>

          <div>
            <PkmnList
              pokemons={this.state.pokemons}
              edit={this.editPokemon}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PkmnForm;
```

PkmnList

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class PkmnList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
  }

  edit(name) {
    this.props.edit(name);
  }

  addPokemon(pokemon) {
    return <li 
              onClick={() => this.edit(pokemon.name)}
              key={pokemon.name}
            >
              {pokemon.name} – {pokemon.type} {pokemon.caught ? '(caught)' : ''}
            </li>
  }

  render() {
    var pokemons = this.props.pokemons;
    var listItems = pokemons.map(this.addPokemon);
    return (
      <ul>
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default PkmnList;
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: you need to bind `addPokemon` as well; otherwise, when you call `pokemons.map(this.addPokemon);`, then `this` will be undefined within `addPokemon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var listItems = pokemons.map(this.addPokemon);
```

Here, you are passing `this.addPokemon` as the function to `map`. But that function is not bound to `this`, so inside of it, `this` is not available.

You either have to bind it explicitly by calling `.bind(this)`, just like you did with the `edit` function:

```
var listItems = pokemons.map(this.addPokemon.bind(this));
```

Or you can pass an arrow function that calls the method:

```
var listItems = pokemons.map(x => this.addPokemon(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `editPokemon` like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.editPokemon = this.editPokemon.bind(this);
  }
```

Or you can also use arrow functions, which have proper scoping:

```
editPokemon = (pokemon) => {
...
}
```